# Android Studio AVD, CRASH, GRADLE PROBLEMS, cannot start up

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

The AVD fails to load, it doesn't recognise it. It asks me to run this manually, which I did via: "Run as Administrator"  on android.bat found in the Android local, platform-tools folder.

I also did all the necessary SDK-platform and tools update for the relevant devices, etc. Still doesn't work.

I followed also a lot of 50 topics on Stack Overflow and Google bug
issue to find my solution to this.  Still no luck.

I even clean project, rebuild project, deleted .gradle folder, tools folder, platform-tools folder to the point of uninstalling everything of Android Studio and their old caches.

Even with new Android Studio installation, I still cannot load up the AVD.

Before I did the whole complete uninstallation, yes I did kill the adb.exe many times via cmd and the rest of the lurking PID processes.

It was reported a bug in Android Studio 7 years ago and with everyone having solutions to this problem. I am still unable to fix this.

**UPDATED** 23.02.17 The issue still NOT resolved. Currently I am using another pc to do my development

---

**More information** 
SDK_HOME = C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Gradle version: 2.14.1
Android Plugin version 2.2.3
Workspace = C:\Users\My Name\MyProjects  (Local, not version control or open source on cloud)

Source of download: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Android Studio 64 bit 2.2.3 version

Laptop: 64 bit PC

Windows 10

Virtual Machines = Mac， Linux

---

**UPDATED**  25.02.17 Log specifically from .gradle assembleDebug log.   (10 seconds after, standstill,   left overnight and couldn't create a new project with NO CODE and couldn't load up Android Studio)

```
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@736e9adb for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Found library resource at jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Trying C:\Users\User\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\tmp\jna8874909424579227886.dll
Found jnidispatch at C:\Users\User\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\tmp\jna8874909424579227886.dll
Looking for library 'user32'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying user32.dll
Found library 'user32' at user32.dll
Loading library manifest C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\nevercreated.xml
Merging main manifest C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Merging library manifest C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\nevercreated.xml
Merging manifest with lower nevercreated.xml:1:1-12:12
Merging applicati

on with lower nevercreated.xml:3:5-11:19
```

[image: Paths]

**UPDATE** 26/2/17   I did a chkdsk /f /r /x check and no bad sectors were found in the hard drive, to ensure that read and write or hard drive issues were the cause of the problem. No issues with the hard drive to affect this issue.

JDK was also reinstalled to ensure that the JDK was not hindering the problem.  No firewalls or firewall programs were enabled, all of them were disabled and uninstalled. No problem even with firewall on for many months before too, so this is not a concern.

All processes were indeed TASKKILL before any other processes would occur. Still no luck.

**UPDATE** 27.2.17    I ordered a new SSD to arrive tomorrow and I will make a new installation (dual-boot) Linux and Windows 10 and install Android Studio on both systems to see whether it will work or not.   So I took the extreme measure to have uninstall and reinstalled the program, no luck, the operating system, no luck and now I will test on a new hard drive soon.  (FINGERS CROSS). Even though there is no bad sectors or error on this hard drive through checking the logs.

**UPDATE** 28.2.17   I reinstalled the whole operating system and I bought another new SDD.  The Android Studio problem is solved.

### REFLECTION

I reinstalled operating system before, but still had Android Studio problems. This leads me to think that it is a hard drive issue, an internet connection (firewall) issue OR Android Studio bug issue.

Unfortunately, I cannot pin point what caused my problem. It randomly happened out of no where.  BUT I hope this will provide comfort to those who experienced almost 10 days of gruelling annoyance.

Comment: Is it showing any error popup/dialog ? What error is it showing..please share the error screenshot/video

Comment: Error  --->  adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary android studio   <--------   Yes, i did the following     TASKKILL -IM adb.exe /f         adb start-server  adb killserver   many times

Comment: Did you add path of platform-tools to System PATH variables ?
Maybe you can try Genymotion emulator.

Comment: PATH, NDK_HOME, ANDROID_NDK_HOME, SDK_HOME, SDK_ROOT, NDK_ROOT,    all of the env variables, yes   added but still no luck

Comment: I'll try Genymotion emulator. I never tried that now

Comment: Are u sure u have installed Intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) ? Try running adb devices/start-server/kill-server from within Android studio terminal...then see if it is starting or not.
Also tell if u r on Mac or Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136369/discussion-between-akshay-mahajan-and-user7568042).

Comment: @user7568042 Share the android sdk path and workspace path, link from where you are downloading the android studio, Operating system, 64-bit or 32-bit. Are you installing as administrator?

Comment: @AnuragSingh  I have updated my post. Please see and yes I am the administrator. I would run the program as administrator and I also made evreryone have admin rights including the program to be run as admin. Just so you know how much I tried and still no luck.    Works fine on my other temporary pc, but not on this.  So I have no clue even after fresh installation.